# error when opening python in terminal

Tags: python, importerror

I accidentally deleted python folders I had on my machine - which is a macbook, running yosemite, version 10.10.2 (14C1510).  I took them out of the trash, but when I try running python, I get this:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

I have read through forums and exported PYTHONHOME to usr/local using this:

```
export PYTHONHOME=usr/local
```

When I try running python now, I only get the last error:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

I located the python2.7 folders - there were four of them and moved them to /usr/local/lib.  Then I typed in:

export PYTHONHOME = /usr/local/lib/python2.7

It gave me the error:

-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export:`/usr/local/lib/python2.7': not a valid identifier

HELP!

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PYTHONHOME should point to the directory of the standard python library. There are a couple of problems with what you are doing at the moment.

1. usr/local is a relative path. You should use an absolute path, i.e. /usr/local
2. /usr/local is likely not a suitable location for your python libraries, it is likely to be something like /usr/local/lib/python2.7 or /usr/local/lib/python3.5

In terminal try using this command:

`ls /usr/local/lib`

Now look through the results for the correct python install that you wish to use. Now set your PYTHONHOME variable using

`export PYTHONHOME=/usr/local/lib/pythonXXX`

replacing the XXX to complete the desired path. Notice how the path contains a leading forward slash to make it an absolute path!

Comment: when i entered ls /usr/local/lib into terminal, here are the options I got:

libyaml-0.2.dylib

libyaml.dylib

libyaml.a 
 
pkgconfig  
                                           
Is there one that is better than another? Or do I not have what i need inside lib?

Comment: How did you install Python? Which operating system are you using? Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: osx yosemite.  

When I check the version, it gives me this 
Python 2.7.8 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.

Comment: I added to the main question so i could format appropriately.

Comment: Maybe also mention that there are no spaces around the equals sign in the `export` syntax.

Comment: Can you `ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7` please? I didn't realise you had partially deleted your python install previously. Did you edit that in with the macbook details!?

I

Comment: @MattDavidson In your `export` command, do you really mean `PYTHONPATH` and not `PYTHONHOME`?